# DropdownButton not updating the value in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

When I try to pick any value from the items. The text doesn't change and it always shows me "Tone 1".

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    // Set landscape orientation
     int _value=1;



    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Tones'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          actions: <Widget>[
         DropdownButton<int>(
        value: _value,
            dropdownColor:Colors.black26,
            items: [
              DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text("Tone 1",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white ,

                    fontSize: 20,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                  ),
                ),
                value: 1,
              ),
              DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text("Tone 2"
                  ,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white ,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                  ),),
                value: 2,
              ),
              DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text("Tone 3",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white ,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    ),),
                  value: 3
              ),
              DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text("Tone 4",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white ,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    ),),
                  value: 4
              )
              ,
              DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text("Tone 5",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white ,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    ),),
                  value: 5
              )

            ],
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _value = value!;
              });
            }),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.send,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                // do something
                List<int> pressedToneList = [];
                final FirebaseFirestore _firebase  = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
                switch (_value) {
                  case 1:
                    pressedToneList=song1;
                    break;

                  case 2:
                    pressedToneList=song2;
                    break;

                  case 3:
                    pressedToneList=song3;
                    break;

                  case 4:
                    pressedToneList=song4;
                    break;

                  case 5:
                    pressedToneList=song5;
                    break;

                  case 6:
                    pressedToneList=song6;
                    break;

                  case 7:
                    pressedToneList=song7;
                    break;
                  case 8:
                    pressedToneList=song8;
                    break;

                  case 9:
                    pressedToneList=song9;
                    break;

                  case 10:
                    pressedToneList=song10;
                }
                await _firebase.collection('Tones').doc('tone').set({"Keys": pressedToneList});
                pressedToneList.clear();
              },
            ),

            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                // do something
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              myTone(1),
              myToneOpposite(3),
              myTone(5),
                myToneOpposite(7),
                myTone(9),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with your code. I have run the same code and I am able to change. Post your full Widget code and what is your `_value`s initial value ?

Comment: It's int _value=1;

Comment: Update your question will full widget code. I too have tried with _value = 1; and it was working

Comment: I just updated it.

Comment: should I post everything or just the build?

Comment: The entire Widget code inside which the Dropdown is being used.

Comment: Have, posted an answer. Check it out it that works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have defined `int _value=1;` inside of your build function.

Hence, it will always be `1` itself since every time widget gets built, the value is being set to 1.

You have to define it as a member variable in your `State` class.

Like this,

```
class ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
    
    int _value = 1;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
```

Then, you can use it the same way, like this

```
DropdownButton<int>(
    value: _value,
```

Finally, you can setState to change it's value like this

```
onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
        _value = value!;
    });
}),
```

Comment: I have another question here regarding this code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67504285/attempt-to-perform-seekto-in-wrong-state-and-error-38-0-flutter  if you can help it would be great!!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Will check it out.